# gzip - performance difference

Tags: bash, gzip, named-pipes

I've a program writing some ASCII-output to a named pipe (`fifo`). I'm trying to measure the throughput of several compression-tools. Therefore I'm using the following statement:

```
cat fifo | gzip -c -1 | pv -b -t -r -a  > file.gz
```

And also:

```
cat file | gzip -c -1 | pv -b -t -r -a > file.gz
```

My question is why is the average throughput from reading the file directly so much higher than reading from a named pipe. The program has an average throughput of 80MB/s when writing unzipped data to disk, so I do not think this is the bottleneck.

Gzip has an average throughput of 5 MB/s when reading from file and about 2 - 2,5 MB/s when reading the output of the program from the named pipe. Other tools even slow down much more (e.g. ltop: file = 9 MB/s; pipe = 3 MB/s).I tried buffering the output to 4K and 16K blocks before piping it to gzip but nothing changed.

So what can I possible do wrong when reading from the named pipe?

Thank in advance

PS: The program used to reproduce the behaviour:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#define SIZE 986

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char line[SIZE];
    size_t size = 0;

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "w");

    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("Could not open pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << "Pipe initialized.\n";

    //read from the file line by line
    while ((size = fread(&line, 1, SIZE, stdin))) {
        fwrite(&line, 1, size, f);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Try sending the compressed data (i.e. `gzip` output) to `/dev/null` to eliminate the disk as a bottleneck....

Comment: Same results with sending the data to `/dev/null`.

Comment: How did you buffer the input to test that? Did you try `unbuffer`ing the input instead?

Comment: I have used `buffer -s 4k` for buffering the output. Sorry but I do not exactly know what you mean with unbuffering the input.

Comment: @Etan `unbuffer cat fifo | gzip -c -1 | pv -b -t -r -a > file.gz` even provides worse results (180K/s)

Comment: As another experiment - eliminate the `cat` by doing `gzip -c -1 < fifo | pv ...` (or even `<fifo gzip -c -1 | pv ...`) - this will at least eliminate some unnecessary processing...

Comment: fifos are fast on my system - approx 1GB/s. Tested like this... `mkfifo pipe; cat pipe > /dev/null &` to create and drain anything arriving in the fifo. Then send 10GB with `dd if=/dev/zero of=pipe bs=1m count=10000`. It takes 10secs.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the fifo is slow, but the script what producing the data.

Simple tests on my system.

In one terminal fill's the pipe

```
mkfifo pipe
seq 10000000 > pipe
```

and on the second terminal simply read it into the `/dev/null`

```
time cat pipe >/dev/null

real    0m6.382s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.204s
```

Now the "from file" test

```
seq 10000000 > file
time cat file >/dev/null

real    0m0.047s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.044s
```

more than 100 times faster!!!

But try:

```
time seq 10000000 > /dev/null

real    0m6.875s
user    0m6.365s
sys     0m0.026s
```

SLOW, the same time as "reading from pipe". So, not the "pipe is slow" but the command what producing the data.

Proof, on one terminal fill the pipe from the file

```
cat file > pipe
```

on the second terminal, read the pipe

```
time cat pipe >/dev/null

real    0m0.199s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.124s
```

same fast as the pure `time cat file >/dev/null`

Comment: But how can it be possible if the application producing the data is very fast when writing to disk and the problems only occur when writing to a named pipe?

Comment: `time cat file > /dev/null` has a real time of 0m0.104s but `cat file > pipe` and `time cat pipe >/dev/null` 0m3.338s.

Comment: @aQuip the result from your last comment is really strange - see my results. Haven't idea. What OS? Mine was OS X, no tweaking.

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS